# Cases operating on both list and atomic expression

Tags: list-manipulation

**Context**

Let us say I have a list such as `{f[1], f[2], g[1]}`
The following

```
 Cases[{f[1], f[2], g[1]}, _f, Infinity]
```

returns as it should

{f(1),f(2)}

**Question**

I would like that the command also works on `f[1]` as in

```
 Cases[f[1], _f, Infinity]
```

which returns *incorrectly* for my purpose

{}

> Would you please tell me how to tweak the command so that it returns

f(1)

Comment: `First@Cases[f[1], _f, {0, ∞}]` or `First[Cases[f[1], _f, {0, ∞}], {}]` to account for the default case.

Comment: @Syed thank you: please turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
First@Cases[f[1], _f, {0, ∞}] (* works with _f only *)
First@Cases[f[1], _g, {0, ∞}] (* results in an error *)
First[Cases[
  f[1], _f, {0, ∞}], {}]  (* includes default case *)
First[Cases[
  f[1], _g, {0, ∞}], {}]  (* includes default case *)
```

> f[1]
>
> First[{}]
>
> f[1]
>
> {}

---

*Explanation*

In order to match `f[1]` we need to match the `Head` of the expression which is at level `0`. The `Head` of an expression is not included by default as `Cases` evaluates.

The documentation states that: `The default value for levelspec in Cases is {1}.`

From the OP: `Cases[{f[1], f[2], g[1]}, _f, ∞]` works as the `Head` of this expression is `List` and other symbols are situated starting at level `1`.

To see this: `TreeForm /@ {f[1], {f[1], f[2], g[1]}}`

---

The expression `f[1]` is not atomic since:

`{f[1][[0]], f[1][[1]], AtomQ[f[1]]}` gives:

> {f, 1, False}

Comment: Although it's hardly documented, it's worth noting that`Cases[...,All]` is equivalent to `Cases[..., {0, ∞}]`